# Onde colocar uma função "toFixed()` para arredondar o valor?

Tags: javascript, funções, arredondamento

Gostaria de arrendondar o valor final do meu código com o `.toFixed()` mas não sei onde colocar.

Aqui está o código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function conversao(fahreinheit) {
    return (5/9) * (fahreinheit-32);
}
console.log(conversao(parseFloat(prompt('Entre com um grau em Fahreinheit: '))));
</script>
```

Comment: tenta criar uma variavel pra guardar o valor da tua conta e depois aplica o .toFIxed() na variavel de retorno

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nós também não porque depende do que quer fazer. Programar tem literalmente uma infinidade de possibilidades e boa parte delas podem produzir o resultado esperado. O primeiro passo para conseguir programar o resultado desejado é saber **exatamente** o resultado que deseja. Saber mais ou menos não adianta muito porque aí deixa muitas possibilidades como válidas, até descobrir que na verdade algumas delas não são tão válidas assim. Várias podem funcionar, mas nem todas estarem certas para o que quer. Discute-se muito sobre como fazer um código correto, neste caso o código está tão feito de qualquer jeito e já tem erros que não faz muita diferença, aprenderia mais se optasse por fazer de uma forma mais organizada, então eu poderia dizer que isto resolve o problema, mesmo não sendo ideal:

```js
function conversao(fahreinheit) {
    return (5/9) * (fahreinheit-32);
}
console.log(conversao(parseFloat(prompt('Entre com um grau em Fahreinheit: '))).toFixed(2));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/ToFixed.js).

Por que eu optei por fazer isto? Sem uma especificação eu acho que a função de conversão (que tem um nome bem ruim) não deveria se preocupar com o número de casas decimais, afinal ela parece só querer fazer o cálculo, em um lugar você pode querer que tenha 2 casas, em outro pode querer 1 ou outro querer 4, ou até acabar com as casas decimais. Se houvesse um especificação de que a conversão teria que ar um resultado com um número de casas ou se a quantidade de casas fosse parametrizada, aí eu teria colocado dentro da função.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode colocar diretamente no retorno da função `return ((5/9) * (fahreinheit-32)).toFixed();`. Segue código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function conversao(fahreinheit) {
    return ((5/9) * (fahreinheit-32)).toFixed();
}
console.log(conversao(parseFloat(prompt('Entre com um grau em Fahreinheit: '))));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o prompt retorna o valor digitado você pode fazer:

```
var p = prompt('Entre com um grau em Fahreinheit: ')
console.log(parseFloat(p).toFixed(2))
```